# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kerastuner (from versions: none) - PyCharm

Tags: python, keras, pip, pycharm

Attempting to install keras_tuner for hyperparameter and in my attempt to install the package, it gives me this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kerastuner (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for kerastuner
```

I've used terminal pip install method along with the three different names for keras tuner, as I want to use the RandomSearch function. What am I doing wrong? Am I using the wrong name? In the python interpreter, when attempting to install the name it only comes up as "kerastuner" but has no versions to choose from.

Comment: Are you looking for this instead? Note the dash: `python -m pip install keras-tuner`

Comment: See also https://keras.io/keras_tuner/#installation

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
pip install keras-tuner --upgrade
```